# Unlock screen programmatically

Tags: android, lockscreen

is there is any way to Unlock Screen by clicking home button. I just did lock screen dynamically by using DeviceAdminReceiver API. as the same way I need to unlock the screen by clicking the home button or some other keys. kindly some one suggest me some ideas about this please.

Comment: Search for "android unlock screen with home button". I am not going to put all the possible solutions here :)